# asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one page which is placed in the Master Page.

In the master page I have 1 dropdown and one GridView, dropdown is display the category, based on the dropdown list selection it will display the list of videos in the Grid.

In the content page I have the video player, in the page load it will play the video by default.

But when I choose the drop down list which is available in the master page, the page is refreshing, SO the video is start play from the first.

The content page should not refresh, So the video will continuously play.

How can I stop the page refresh in the content page?

All are in master page.

`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

```
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_Channel" Width="220px" CssClass="ddl" 
                            AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="drp_Channel_SelectedIndexChanged">
                      <asp:ListItem>-- Select Channels --</asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>
                   </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

```
                            <asp:GridView ID="grd_Video" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="LinkName"
                            GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" Width="100%" EmptyDataText="No Videos Found" >
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="img_Video" runat="server" BorderColor="#666699" CssClass="imgbox"
                                            ImageUrl='<%#(string)FormatImageUrl((string)Eval("Video_Thumbnail")) %>' 
                                            CommandName="imgClick" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Video_ID")%>' 
                                            BorderWidth="0px" Height="40px" ToolTip="Click to view video" Width="50px" 
                                            BorderStyle="Double" />
                                    
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_VideoName" runat="server" ToolTip="Click to view video" 
                                            CommandName="lnkClick" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Video_ID")%>' 
                                            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Video_Name") %>' 
                                            CssClass="linkVideo" Width="130px"></asp:LinkButton> 
                                        
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#cccccc" />
                            
                        </asp:GridView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>`
```

in code behind for binding grid,

```
DataTable dt1Video = new MDBusiness.MDSUser().GetVideo(intNetId, intChanId, intCatId);
                grd_Video.DataSource = dt1Video;
                grd_Video.DataBind();
                up1.Update();
                up2.Update();
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `AutoPostBack = "False"` on your dropdownlist to stop the postback from occurring.  Users will then be able to change the dropdownlist without anything happening.

You'll need to use AJAX with your dropdownlist if you want to be able to use it without the postback.

Answer (score 3):

for a quick answer

- Install [ASP.NET AJAX library](http://www.asp.net/ajax/downloads/)
- Wrap the GridView in a UpdatePanel
- Set the trigger to be the DropDownList

Done :)

**Remember** to see this [Screencast](http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/video-183.aspx)... it is exactly what you are after!